# include PHP script in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

i have a PHP script that i want to include it in My laravel App.so i try to build a controller and to put on it the script.the role of the  PHP scripts is to get data from an csv file and insert it in the database.But when i run it noting happen.
so this is my Job wait controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
include(app_path() . '/config.php');
include(app_path() . '/CDM/entities/job_en_wait.php');
include(app_path() . '/CDM/core/job_en_waitC.php');

use App\job_en_wait;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JobWaitController extends Controller
 {
 //
function dos(){

 $dir = app_path(). '/files/';

$scan = scandir($dir);

$file = fopen($dir.$scan[4], "r");

print_r($scan[4]);

echo "<br>";

$data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",");

while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    if ($data[0]!=";;;;;") {
      $liste=explode(";",$data[0]);
      //print_r($liste);

     $job_en_wait=new job_en_wait(0,$liste[0],$liste[1],$liste[2],$liste[3],$liste[4],$liste[5],$liste[6],$liste[7],$liste[8],$liste[9],$liste[10]);

      $job_en_waitController=new job_en_waitC();

      $job_en_waitController->afficherjob_en_wait($job_en_wait);
      $job_en_waitController->ajouterjob_en_wait($job_en_wait);
      //echo "<br>job_en_wait integré avec succes <br>";
    }

}

fclose($file);


  }
  }
```

this is job_waitC.php:

```
<?PHP

    class job_en_waitC {


    function afficherjob_en_wait ($job_en_wait){
    echo "id: ".$job_en_wait->getid()."<br>";
    echo "client: ".$job_en_wait->getclient()."<br>";
    echo "session: ".$job_en_wait->getsession()."<br>";
    echo "info_session: ".$job_en_wait->getinfo_session()."<br>";
    echo "UPROC: ".$job_en_wait->getUPROC()."<br>";
    echo "num_session: ".$job_en_wait->getnum_session()."<br>";
    echo "num_exec: ".$job_en_wait->getnum_exec()."<br>";

    echo "date_debut: ".$job_en_wait->getdate_debut()."<br>";
    $hd=date_create($job_en_wait->getheure_debut());
    echo "heure_debut :".date_format($hd,"g:i:s A")."<br>";

    echo "date_fin: ".$job_en_wait->getdate_fin()."<br>";
    $hf=date_create($job_en_wait->getheure_fin());
    echo "heure_fin :".date_format($hf,"g:i:s A")."<br>";
    echo "status: ".$job_en_wait->getstatus()."<br>";

   }

   function ajouterjob_en_wait($job_en_wait){
    $date_debut=$job_en_wait->getdate_debut();
    $date_fin=$job_en_wait->getdate_fin();

    /*$heure_debut=date_create($job_en_wait->getheure_debut());
    $final_heure_debut=date_format($heure_debut,"m/d/Y H:i:s");

    $heure_fin=date_create($job_en_wait->getheure_fin());
    $final_fin_debut=date_format($heure_fin,"m/d/Y H:i:s");*/
    $heure_debut=$job_en_wait->getheure_debut();
    $heure_fin=$job_en_wait->getheure_fin();
    //echo "job_en_wait->getheure_fin ".$job_en_wait->getheure_fin();
    $sql="INSERT into job_en_wait (client,session,info_session,UPROC,num_session,num_exec,date_debut,heure_debut,date_fin,heure_fin,status)
     values (:client,:session,:info_session,:UPROC,:num_session,:num_exec,STR_TO_DATE('$date_debut','%d/%m/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('05/12/2020 $heure_debut','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'),STR_TO_DATE('$date_fin','%d/%m/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('05/12/2020 $heure_fin','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'),:status)";
    //echo "request :".$sql."<br>";
    $db = config::getConnexion();
    try{
    $req=$db->prepare($sql);

    $client=$job_en_wait->getclient();
    $session=$job_en_wait->getsession();
    $info_session=$job_en_wait->getinfo_session();
    $UPROC=$job_en_wait->getUPROC();
    $num_session=$job_en_wait->getnum_session();
    $num_exec=$job_en_wait->getnum_exec();

    $date_debut=$job_en_wait->getdate_debut();
    $heure_debut=$job_en_wait->getheure_debut();
    $date_fin=$job_en_wait->getdate_fin();
    $heure_fin=$job_en_wait->getheure_fin();

    $status=$job_en_wait->getstatus();


    $req->bindValue(':client',$client);
    $req->bindValue(':session',$session);
    $req->bindValue(':info_session',$info_session);
    $req->bindValue(':UPROC',$UPROC);
    $req->bindValue(':num_session',$num_session);
    $req->bindValue(':num_exec',$num_exec);

    $req->bindValue(':status',$status);

        $req->execute();

    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Erreur exec erreur: '.$e->getMessage();
    }

}

function afficherjobs_en_wait(){
    //$sql="SElECT * From job_en_wait e inner join formationphp.job_en_wait a on e.cin= a.cin";
    $sql="SElECT * From job_en_wait";
    $db = config::getConnexion();
    try{
    $liste=$db->query($sql);
    return $liste;
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        die('Erreur: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}


} 

?>
```

And this is job_en_wait.php:

```
<?PHP
class job_en_wait{

private $id;
private $client;
private $session;
private $info_session;
private $UPROC;
private $num_session;
private $num_exec;
private $date_debut;
private $heure_debut;
private $date_fin;
private $heure_fin;
private $status;

function __construct($id,$client,$session,$info_session,$UPROC,$num_session,$num_exec,$date_debut,$heure_debut,$date_fin,$heure_fin,$status){
$this->id=$id;
$this->client=$client;
$this->session=$session;
$this->info_session=$info_session;
$this->UPROC=$UPROC;
$this->num_session=$num_session;
$this->num_exec=$num_exec;
$this->date_debut=$date_debut;
$this->heure_debut=$heure_debut;
$this->date_fin=$date_fin;
$this->heure_fin=$heure_fin;
$this->status=$status;
}
function getid(){
    return $this->id;
}
function getclient(){
    return $this->client;
}
function getsession(){
    return $this->session;
}
function getinfo_session(){
    return $this->info_session;
}
function getUPROC(){
    return $this->UPROC;
}
function getnum_session(){
    return $this->num_session;
}
function getnum_exec(){
    return $this->num_exec;
}
function getdate_debut(){
    return $this->date_debut;
}
function getheure_debut(){
    return $this->heure_debut;
}
function getdate_fin(){
    return $this->date_fin;
}
function getheure_fin(){
    return $this->heure_fin;
}
function getstatus(){
    return $this->status;
}



function setclient($client){
    $this->client=$client;
}

function setsession($session){
    $this->session=$session;
}


function setinfo_session($info_session){
    $this->info_session=$info_session;
}

function setUPROC($UPROC){
    $this->UPROC=$UPROC;
}

function setnum_session($num_session){
    $this->num_session=$num_session;
}

function setnum_exec($num_exec){
    $this->num_exec=$num_exec;
}


function setdate_debut($date_debut){
    $this->date_debut=$date_debut;
}

function setheure_debut($heure_debut){
    $this->heure_debut=$heure_debut;
}

function setdate_fin($date_fin){
    $this->date_fin=$date_fin;
  }

    function setheure_fin($heure_fin){
    $this->heure_fin=$heure_fin;
   }


   function setstatus($status){
    $this->status=$status;
  }




   }

   ?>
```

Comment: 1. It is common to use autoloading in Laravel dont use include. 2. You should never do echos. 3. You file names, indention or function name does not align to any standard.  4. You are using a lot of old school PHP functions use Laravel components like storage etc.

Comment: `when i run it noting happen` - how do you run it?  What do your web server, PHP, and Laravel logs show?  Have you done some basic debugging, eg does it even reach your `dos()` method?

Comment: @Don'tPanic it reach the dos() method successfully but it didn't insert in the DB anything

Answer (score 0):

This goes against PSR convention. There's a much cleaner way of doing this.
There's a few code convention mistakes you've made in your application.

1. You should follow PSR naming for namespaces:
   https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/
2. You should create a seperate config file. so in your laravel config
   folder you  should create a config file which is accessible by
   config() function.

an example of how this would like is:
1) make a folder in /app/Models
2) put JobWait as a laravel model (You don't need to do all the sql, you should use eloquent
specify the namespace of JobWait as "use App/Models;"

I'd fully suggest converting the JobWait class you are using to be a Laravel Model.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpVE5RfcuTQ